# How to properly configure user role relationship in nestjs and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have been stuck with this for some time. I have a usertype/role that should have a default value if the usertype/role is not passed from the body. if the usertype/role is passed then the one from the user will be used.

I will appreciate if someone can help me out with this. I can use this idea in other components with similar structures. Thanks

This is the error I am getting when I initiate registration

> {   "statusCode": 400,   "message": [
>       "usertype.nested property usertype must be either object or array"   ],   "error": "Bad Request" }

1. How do I pass usertype/role from the body?
2. How do I set a default value in the schema/document/dto?
3. How do I handle this in the service?

This is what I have done

Schema

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    },
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
     usertype: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'UserType',
        default: ''
    },
})
```

interface

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { UserType } from '../../usertype/interface/usertype.interface'

export interface User extends Document {
    userId: string;
    firstname: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
    usertype: UserType;
}
```

Here is the createdto

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsString, MinLength, IsEmail, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { UserType } from 'src/usertype/interface/usertype.interface';

export class CreateUserDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsString()
    firstname: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @MinLength(6, { message: "Your Password should be at least 6 characters" })
    password: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @ValidateNested()
    usertype: UserType;

}
```

```
    //register user
    async register(createDTO: CreateUserDto, userType: CreateUserTypeDTO): Promise<User> {

        const { email } = createDTO;
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email })

        if (user) {
            throw new HttpException('User already exists', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        const createdUser = await this.userModel.create({
            ...createDTO,
            usertype: userType
        });

        await createdUser.save();
        return createdUser;
    }
```